# Difference between a global variable and variable defined in main?

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, global-variables

I am confused on the difference between creating a `global` variable vs defining a variable in `main`. I have a very specific example that I would like explained. Here is the specific code:

```
def f():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    print("Thank you for entering your username")

#I want to be able to use the "username" variable outside of the "f" function
#and use it multiple times throughout my code
print(f"Your username is: {username}")
```

Here is the solution I initially thought was correct:

```
def f():
    global username
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    print("Thank you for entering your username")
f()
print(f"Your username is: {username}")
```

Here is the solution that I was told was the **actual** correct/preferred way:

```
def f():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    print("Thank you for entering your username")
    return username

username = f()
print(f"Your username is: {username}")
```

The reasoning for the second solution was that it is better to return a variable and creating a `global` variable using the `global` keyword is very discouraged/should be avoided, but I'm confused because I thought the second solution also creates a variable that is defined in the `global` scope since they are defining the variable in `main` ([here is the article I read which confirmed this concept of `global` vs `main` variables](https://stackabuse.com/local-and-global-variables-in-python/#:%7E:text=a%20variable%20defined%20in%20the%20main%20program%20belongs%20to%20the%20global%20namespace%2C%20that%20can%20be%20accessed%20by%20any%20function%20in%20your%20Python%20program), if someone can confirm this is correct it would be helpful as well since I have multiple questions regarding this).

I am confused on this Python concept and why the second solution is a better/preferred method of solution. Can someone explain?

Comment: mutable global state is an antipattern. It leads to "spaghetti code". It makes your code harder to test and harder to understand. it is also less flexible.

Comment: see this related question on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one does create a global variable. The critical difference, though, is that your function does not *rely* on it. The user of your function could also write

```
def f():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    print("Thank you for entering your username")
    return username

name_of_user = f()
print(f"Your username is: {name_of_user}")
```

Note that there is *no* dependence on the name your *function* uses to store the input and the name the *caller* uses to receive it. Your local variable `username` does not exist outside your function, and your function knows nothing about how the value it returns will be used, or even it is used at all.

Comment: Does this mean the answer by @John is not correct? It seems like he was saying that the ```global``` keyword worked between modules but [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Explain-the-visibility-of-global-variables-in-imported-modules-in-Python) says otherwise. Could you verify?

Comment: I'm not sure what John's first example is meant to show. `f` and `g` create two differnt global variables (`lib1.username` and `lib2.username`, respectively) when called, but the `print` call in `main` doesn't try to print either one; it tries to print the undefined `main.username`.

Answer (score 0):

By using a local variable you decrease the dependencies between your components,therefore decreasing the complexity of your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).